# Do I need NoSQL solution like Elasticsearch if I want to query 2 billion rows in one table or MySQL is enough?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, nosql

I have application that will go to production soon. Application will insert approximately 10 million rows in one table that has 16 columns in Amazon Aurora MySQL database. Column types are bigint, int, bit, datetime. Other tables in database have less than 3 thousand rows.
We will make SQL queries with few inner joins and where clause will only have datetime range and bigint value of one column on that large table in last 6 months. That means we will have 2 billion rows in that large table.
Data older than 6 months will be deleted from that large table.
If I put index on date column it will probably slow insert command and maybe querying will still be slow.
If I use Elasticsearch and create some application task that will insert rows into multiple shards grouped by date every 5 minutes and create MySQL database backups every 3 days and delete rows older than 3 days, maybe querying data will be faster.
What do you think?
Is it better and more efficient to use Elasticsearch or MySQL is enough?

Comment: Are you saying your where condition for the dayetime will always be the last 6 months, and that's all the data you intend to keep in the table anyway?  Or that you will be looking for a subset of the last 6 months for any given query?   2 billion rows total you say, but if each query only needs a particular bigint value, how many rows will have that value on average or expected maximum?

Comment: Where will be subset of the last 6 months for example WHERE date >= '2022-03-23' AND date <= '2022-03-27' AND someColumn=98446592127 . 6 months after begining of production large table will always be approximately 2 billion rows. Subset query result will be limited to 20 rows because we implemented server side pagination.

Comment: is someColumn always the same column?  if so, just index (someColumn,date) and you should see good results.   though if this is really a datetime, `date <= '2022-03-27'` is a weird thing to do; it includes only `2022-03-27 00:00:00` but not any later times that day

Comment: Yes. someColumn is type date not datetime. Is it enough to just put index on these two columns someColumn date. Will query run in few seconds or it will be much slower than Elasticsearch? Will this slow insert command because we have 2 billion rows in table?

Comment: extra indexes slow down inserts by only a very little bit.  I would be surprised if a query like what you describe took even a tenth of a second, if you have a muticolumn index with the bigint first and the date second.  but try it and see; maybe there's some complexity you haven't described well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the usage you are giving to your data (analysis or log handling are two completely different purposes) and how you access it.

What are you worried about?

- Query times: indexing the column that will be more queried will increase the speed. Also, designing this table with a [snowflake shceme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_schema) may help. There are other things like picking a [column-oriented DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS) that could improve the speeds. Also, depending on the type of data you are storing (maybe you are using dates, so Timescale could help). If this is all about logging, then Elasticsearch can do this pretty nicely, but it seems like you already know what data will fit.
- Storage issues: if you are worried about really large tables, there are database systems that are distributed (eg. [VoltDB](https://docs.voltdb.com/UsingVoltDB/IntroHowVoltDBWorks.php)). Which has redundancy as well.
- The last thing I can think of is how it will fit in your architecture. If you are already using MySQL, you don't really need for 10 million rows to change a lot of things. The above answer is in case you start increasing the size, and you need some specific solutions.

Comment: Thanks on answer. Everything will be hosted on Amazon AWS. They have cloud solution Aurora MySQL and Amazon OpenSearch Service for Elasticsearch. I think maybe Elasticsearch will be easiest and most efficient solution.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I wasn't sure if it was a hybrid infrastructure. I don't know much cloud. I guess you've already found this, but in case you didn't here is a list of all AWS databases with their purposes. Made by Amazon. [https://aws.amazon.com/products/databases/](https://aws.amazon.com/products/databases/). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**If MySQL only...**

1 billion or 10 million -- MySQL can handle either.  But there are limitations on what queries will run "fast".

I need to see a specific query.

**Purging old data** -- Plan on `PARTITIONing` by the datetime column.  Otherwise, the Delete will be terribly slow.  See [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)  For "6 months", I recommend 8 monthly or 29 weekly partitions.  See the link for a discussion of the starting and "future" partitions.

**DATE / DATETIME**

It is *usually* unwise to have an index *stating* with the datatime.  I need to see your query to go into more detail on what the index should look like.

A `DATE` column is equivalent to a `DATETIME` for midnight of that morning.  I recommend the following pattern for testing against a date or datetime range.  It avoids leap issues, midnight issues, etc, etc.  This correctly tests for a one-week range:

```
WHERE d >= '2022-04-24'
  AND d  < '2022-04-24' + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

You want a 1 day range?

```
WHERE d >= '2022-04-24'
  AND d  < '2022-04-24' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Or noon to noon the next day:

```
WHERE d >= '2022-04-24 12:00:00'
  AND d  < '2022-04-24 12:00:00' + INTERVAL 24 HOUR
```

Those work for DATE, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP -- with or without fractional seconds.

**Extra indexes** are not a big deal.  By "10M rows, did you mean 10M/day?  That is 120/second (or more during spikes).  That is "moderate", assuming SSD drives are being used.

Is your INSERT application single-threaded?  Can it batch, say, 100 rows at a time?

If latitude/longitude are involved, say so; that is a different kettle of fish.

Will 2 billion rows slow down Inserts?  I need to see the tentative list of indexes (PRIMARY, UNIQUE, SPATIAL, FULLTEXT, and others).  Properly designed, I don't see a problem.

**Normalization**

You should normalize the Fact table to help with disk space (hence speed), but don't over-normalize.  To advise further, I need a feel for the data, not just the datatypes.  Do not normalize datetime columns or any other columns to be tested as a "range"; such values need to be in the Fact table.

What you have said so far does not indicate the need for sharding (in a MySQL-only implementation).

(I cannot address whether ElasticSearch would be better or worse that MySQL.  NoSQL requires re-inventing much of what MySQL or ES do automatically.)